# Error creating DataBase with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I try to create a database structure using LinQ. The tables have references to each other. Following the hints here on SO I currently have the following Code: (part of)

```
[Database]
public class SqlData : DataContext
{     
    public Table<Benutzer> Benutzers;      
    public Table<Standort> Standorts;

    public SqlData(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)   { }

    public void CreateDb()
    {            
        CreateDatabase();
    }
}

[Table(Name = "tqStandort")]
public class Standort
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "BigInt IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public int Id;
    [Column]
    public string Name;
}

[Table(Name = "tqBenutzer")]
public class Benutzer
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "BigInt IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public int Id;

    [Column(Name = "IdStandort")]
    private int? _idStandort;
    private EntityRef<Standort> _standort;

   [Association(Name = "FK_Benutzer_Standort", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_standort", ThisKey = "_idStandort")]
    public Standort IdStandort
    {
        get { return _standort.Entity; }
        set { _standort.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

When CreateDatabase() is called I receive the following Error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Column
>   'tqStandort.Id' is not the same data type as referencing column
>   'tqBenutzer.IdStandort' in foreign key 'FK_Benutzer_Standort'. Could
>   not create constraint

Where is my mistake?

(UPDATE):
This would be the SQL-Structure I would like to achieve:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tqStandort](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tqStandort] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tqBenutzer](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdStandort] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tqBenutzer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tqBenutzer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tqBenutzer_tqStandort] FOREIGN KEY([IdStandort])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tqStandort] ([Id])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns that you use in association should have same type.
Change to:

```
private long? _idStandort;
```

or:

```
[Table(Name = "tqStandort")]
public class Standort
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "Int IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public int Id;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just one second before I found out myself. :) Yep. Stupid mistake Thanks, Pal.